# Error Installing MCM (Multi Cloud Manager) 3.1.1 on ICP 3.1.1

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ubuntu-16.04, ibm-cloud-private

**Step by step I'm got error**

1. Login cloudctl like below :

```
root@icp-master:~/mcm-3.1.1# cloudctl login -a https://swgcluster.icp:8443 -n kube-system --skip-ssl-validation

Username> admin

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

Targeted account swgcluster Account (id-swgcluster-account)

Targeted namespace kube-system

Configuring kubectl ...
Property "clusters.swgcluster" unset.
Property "users.swgcluster-user" unset.
Property "contexts.swgcluster-context" unset.
Cluster "swgcluster" set.
User "swgcluster-user" set.
Context "swgcluster-context" created.
Switched to context "swgcluster-context".
OK

Configuring helm: /root/.helm
OK
```

2. After that login docker :

```
root@icp-master:~/mcm-3.1.1# docker login swgcluster.icp:8500
Username (admin): admin
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

3. **Error** When load PPA archive, got message "(Are you logged in to the docker registry?)":

```
root@icp-master:~/mcm-3.1.1# cloudctl catalog load-ppa-archive -a mcm-3.1.1-amd64.tgz --registry swgcluster.icp:8500
Expanding archive
OK

Importing docker images
  Processing image: mcm-compliance:3.1.1
    Loading Image
    Tagging Image
    Pushing image as: swgcluster.icp:8500/mcm-compliance:3.1.1
FAILED
Error during 'docker push swgcluster.icp:8500/mcm-compliance:3.1.1': 
   The push refers to repository [swgcluster.icp:8500/mcm-compliance]
897913ab6781: Preparing
9151cff5fa59: Preparing
50e922e82331: Preparing
fe5040b266fd: Preparing
df64d3292fd6: Preparing
unauthorized: authentication required

(Are you logged in to the docker registry?)
```

My step on above got wrong or not? or there is have something wrong?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me Fix It on Step 3, Using Commands :

**cloudctl catalog load-ppa-archive -a mcm-3.1.1-amd64.tgz --registry swgcluster.icp:8500/*kube-system***

Just Added `/kube-system` on Private Docker Registry after Cluster Name & Port